# How should I implement hit detection netcode for AI enemies in a co-op first-person-shooter?

Tags: networking, ai

I'm working on a FPS/sandbox game that has multiplayer but no PvP. Since the game has no PvP, I'm trying to make the networking code favor the player as much as possible.

For example, I allow the game-clients to decide whether a shot hit/missed an enemy, rather than having the game-server verify. I also allow the game-clients to decide where they are on the map -- with no verification from the server.

This opens the doors for cheaters, but in a PvE game I don't care so much.

However, I don't know how to design the enemy AI. If a player is lagging, the server doesn't know that player's real location, so how could I ensure that the player actually saw himself get attacked by an enemy (for example, a Zombie) before the server registered a hit on the player?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't care about cheaters at all (I personally doubt that cooperative games are completely uninteresting to cheaters, but this is the premise of the question), then you could let the clients not just calculate the hits they make but also the hits they receive.

This means all hits on the player get resolved according to the world-state as perceived by the player. So there will be no situation where the player gets damaged by an attack they didn't see connect.

While this favors players, it handicaps the AI. When they make decisions solely based on the server-sided world state which then get resolved according to the client-sided world-state, they will often miss the players. In order to allow the AI to deal with that handicap, you will have to add latency considerations to your enemy AI. So when the AI wants to attack a player who has a latency of 100ms, it would extrapolate the target's current movement vector and attack the location where it will be in 100ms.

As long as the player only pays attention to themselves and their opponents, the hit detection will appear very plausible. The AI might not seem as precise as it could be. But the player will usually expect the AI opponents to not have perfect aim, so this won't be an issue. The drawback is that the game might start to look implausible when they observe opponents attacking their teammates. The player might see attacks which clearly connect from their own point of views, but don't appear to do any damage because from the teammate's point of view they dodged the attack.

Comment: I wonder how the zombie (enemy AI) could even navigate to a lagging player; extrapolating for 100ms sounds workable, but much beyond that would just look silly.

Comment: @Mr.Smith You could ask the same question about the navigation decisions of human opponents in a deathmatch multiplayer FPS. The game experience of multiplayer FPS games always suffers when different actors run on different computers with high network latencies between them. No matter which actors are bots and which are human.